# NextJs Google fonts issue - Only one font gets displayed

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, sanity

I'm connecting Google Fonts link to the HEAD section in _app.js file of my NextJs application. The link contains two fonts.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;700&family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap
```

However when I mention font-family in sass files of modules, they don't seem to work. The webpage is displaying default browser fonts. How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the fonts. it will download too many variation. pick ones that you want and copy them to "public/fonts" directory.

Then in main.scss (or in a partial), use it like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "PressStart2P";
  src: url("/fonts/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

now you can use this family in scss as follow:

```
font-family: "PressStart2P";
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the font family, personally I like to run them through [transfonter.org](https://transfonter.org) to make them browser compatible as well. Tick the following boxes:

- TTF
- EOT
- WOFF
- WOFF2

On download it will then provide you all the fonts with a `@font-face` stylesheet which will handle the different font face declarations for you as well then just fix your file paths.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Badhorse';
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/Badhorse-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/Badhorse-Regular.eot?#iefix')
      format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Badhorse-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Badhorse-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Badhorse-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

```
 font-family: "Badhorse", san-serif; // ensure fallback system fonts
```

Comment: I choose the 4 that I mentioned in the above - Different browsers require different font type files. If you load them in alike the above example, users browsers will be able to require the specific font file they need

Comment: Theres a nice image on here that shows you the font types and their capability on browsers
https://creativemarket.com/blog/the-missing-guide-to-font-formats

Comment: I need help on a few more stuff regarding font usage. Do you mind if I follow you on Twitter?

Comment: Go ahead, just drop me an inbox @OliverHeward :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit the index.js, remove the font "Inter" import and style references from it.